# Android. Не получается сделать сплешскрин на весь экран

Tags: android

При создании приложения в Android Studio хочу сделать заставку (изображение). При запуске приложения должна появляться эта картинка, несколько секунд висит (или отображается загрузка приложения), а потом запускается следующая активность. Но проблема в том, что всегда видна сверху панель с названием приложения (тулбар, action-бар или как он правильно называется). А хочется, чтобы оно на весь экран отображалось. Я пробовал выбирать различные темы, но ничего не помогло. Тестирую на физическом устройстве (android 5.1). Пишу код на API 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот не большой пример. Добавьте в ваш манифест ссылку на Сплэш активити

```
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

указанная выше активити имеет ссылку на следующую тему

```
    <style name="Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте у активити пропишите данный атрибут, должно помочь:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```